# Conda: Create venv from requirements using pip while forcing package version

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, requirements.txt

We have a `requirements.yml`

```
name:
- env_name
dependencies:
-packageA
-packageB
-pip
-pip:
 - pkgC==ver_1
 - pkgD==ver_1
```

Now `pkgC` have dependency for `pkgD` but with version `ver_2`, but I want to have the `pkgD` in version `ver_1`. The above is not installing the `pkgD==ver_1` saying:

```
Error: Invalid requirement pkgD==ver_1
```

I can achieve this by creating the conda env using the `requirements.yml` without explicit last line (without pkgD==ver_1) and then activating it and executing:

```
<env_name> $ conda install pkgD==ver_1
```

which will unsinstall the `pkgD==ver_2` and install `pkgD==ver_1`

BUT:

**How can I achieve this using *only the requirements.yml* file while creating the conda virtual env?**

EDIT:
If it helps: so pkgC is confluent-kafka[avro]=1.1.0 and pkgD is avro-python==1.8.2

Comment: It would really help to know which secret packages those are, some problems with invalid requirements are due to versions of specific packages. Apart from that, if `pkgC==ver_1` needs `pkgD==ver_2`, why would you install `pkgD==ver_1`? For the looks, `pkgC` depends just on any version of `pkgD`, otherwise your manual install would be breaking you code. If this is the case, installing `pkgD` before `pkgC` would solve your problem, as by the time pip would try to install `pkgC`, dependency would already be satisfied.

Comment: so `pkgC` is `confluent-kafka[avro]=1.1.0` and `pkgD` is `avro-python==1.8.2`

Comment: This looks like a typo error. If you check PyPI, it's either `avro-python3` or just `avro` (presumably for Python 2?).